# Objectify generics compile time error with incompatible objects in Java 7

Tags: java, objectify

In java 6 the following line compiles however in Java 7 I get an incompatible type error (See below). Any ideas what is going on here?

```
Player player = new FPlayer();
player.setId("SomeString");
player.setWId(123456, "SomeString");

Key<Player> keyForPlayer = ofy().save().entity(player).now();
```

Gets a compile time error

```
incompatible types
required: com.googlecode.objectify.Key<com.XX.XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXX.Player>
found:    com.googlecode.objectify.Key<java.lang.Object>
```

Comment: Can you post some more code, including the declaration of SomeType? Also, what you have posted won't compile at all - SomeType is either the type or the variable passed into entity(), it can't be both.

Comment: Corrected, I have to obfuscate the internal types sorry. However, It is a google proto buffer generated message class.

Comment: There is not enough information here. Unless you can post a more complete test case, it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: Not sure it helps but here is more code.

Comment: Could you at least post enough code to actually reproduces the problem? Perhaps in the process of coming up with a minimal example you will will find out where the problem is, but I suspect it is not in the code you've posted.